# select the entire week details by a single date in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_timesheet_entry
( 

        Id int NULL,
    date_enter date NULL,
    proj_type char(50) NULL,
    build_no char(10) NULL,
    ticket_no int NULL,
    wrk_hr varchar(20) NULL,
    wrk_code varchar(20) NULL,
    comments varchar(50) NULL,
    active bit NULL
)
```

Here when I enter the date in date_enter column,need to display the entire week details from monday to sunday. Now I need the stored procedure for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you right, but I'm guessing you want all rows from the table that are within a given week?

If so, you can select them like this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT * FROM tbl_timesheet_entry 
WHERE datepart(week, date_enter) = 23 AND year(date_enter) = 2014
```

to get week 23 of year 2014.

The "SET DATEFIRST 1" part is because by default SQL Server weeks start on Sundays, not Mondays.